# Find the last value in a "rolled-over" sequence with a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, string, series

Suppose I had a set of alpha-character identifiers of a set length, e.g. always five letters, and they are assigned in such a way that they are always incremented sequentially (GGGGZ --> GGGHA, etc.).   Now, if I get to ZZZZZ, since the length is fixed, I must "roll over" to AAAAA.  I might have a contiguous block from ZZZAA through AAAAM.  I want to write a sproc that will give me the "next" identifier, in this case AAAAN.

If I didn't have this "rolling over" issue, of course, I'd just ORDER BY DESC and grab the top result.  But I'm at a bit of a loss now -- and it doesn't help at all that SQL is not my strongest language.

If I *have* to I can move this to my C# calling code, but a sproc would be a better fit.

ETA: I would like to avoid changing the schema (new column *or* new table); I'd rather just be able to "figure it out".  I might even prefer to do it brute force (e.g. start at the lowest value and increment until I find a "hole"), even though that could get expensive.  If you have an answer that does not modify the schema, it'd be a better solution for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the lowest-impact solution for my needs is to add an identity column.  The one thing I can guarantee is that the ordering will be such that entries that should "come first" will be added first -- I'll never add one with identifier BBBB, then go back and add BBBA later.  If I didn't have that constraint, obviously it wouldn't work, but as it stands, I can just order by the identity column and get the sort I want.

I'll keep thinking about the other suggestions -- maybe if they "click" in my head, they'll look like a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that I think will give you your Next value.  I created 3 functions.  The table is just my simulation of the table.column with your alpha ids (I used MyTable.AlphaID).  I assume that it's as you implied and there is one contiguous block of five-character uppercase alphabetic strings (AlphaID):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (AlphaID char(5) PRIMARY KEY)
GO
-- Play with different population scenarios for testing
INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES ('ZZZZY')
INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES ('ZZZZZ')
INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES ('AAAAA')
INSERT dbo.MyTable VALUES ('AAAAB')
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt','FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt (@AlphaID char(5))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 1+ ASCII(SUBSTRING(@AlphaID,5,1))-65
              + ((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@AlphaID,4,1))-65) * 26)
              + ((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@AlphaID,3,1))-65) * POWER(26,2))
              + ((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@AlphaID,2,1))-65) * POWER(26,3))
              + ((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@AlphaID,1,1))-65) * POWER(26,4))
END
GO 

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID','FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID (@ID int)
RETURNS char(5)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CHAR((@ID-1) / POWER(26,4) + 65)
      + CHAR ((@ID-1) % POWER(26,4) / POWER(26,3) + 65)
      + CHAR ((@ID-1) % POWER(26,3) / POWER(26,2) + 65)
      + CHAR ((@ID-1) % POWER(26,2) / 26 + 65)
      + CHAR ((@ID-1) % 26 + 65)

END
GO 
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetNextAlphaID','FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNextAlphaID
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextAlphaID ()
RETURNS char(5)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MaxID char(5), @ReturnVal char(5)
    SELECT @MaxID = MAX(AlphaID) FROM dbo.MyTable
    IF @MaxID < 'ZZZZZ'
        RETURN dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID(dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt(@MaxID)+1)
    IF @MaxID IS NULL
        RETURN 'AAAAA'
    SELECT @MaxID = MAX(AlphaID) 
    FROM dbo.MyTable 
    WHERE AlphaID < dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.MyTable))
    IF @MaxID IS NULL
        RETURN 'AAAAA'
    RETURN dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID(dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt(@MaxID)+1)
END
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt(AlphaID)
GO
SELECT  dbo.GetNextAlphaID () AS 'NextAlphaID'
```

By the way, if you don't want to assume contiguity, you can do as you suggested and (if there's a 'ZZZZZ' row) use the first gap in the sequence.  Replace the last function with this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetNextAlphaID_2','FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetNextAlphaID_2
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNextAlphaID_2 ()
RETURNS char(5)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MaxID char(5), @ReturnVal char(5)
    SELECT @MaxID = MAX(AlphaID) FROM dbo.MyTable
    IF @MaxID < 'ZZZZZ'
        RETURN dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID(dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt(@MaxID)+1)
    IF @MaxID IS NULL
        RETURN 'AAAAA'
    SELECT TOP 1 @MaxID=M1.AlphaID
    FROM dbo.Mytable M1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.MyTable M2 
                      WHERE AlphaID = dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID(dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt(M1.AlphaID) + 1 )
                     )
    ORDER BY M1.AlphaID
    IF @MaxID IS NULL
        RETURN 'AAAAA'
    RETURN dbo.ConvertIntToAlphaID(dbo.ConvertAlphaIDToInt(@MaxID)+1)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to store the last allocated identifier in the sequence.

For example, store it in another table that has one column & one row.

```
CREATE TABLE CurrentMaxId (
    Id CHAR(6) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CurrentMaxId (Id) VALUES ('AAAAAA');
```

Each time you allocate a new identifier, you'd fetch the value in that tiny table, increment it, and store that value in your main table as well as updating the value in `CurrentMaxId`.

The usual caveats apply with respect to concurrency, table-locking, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd have tried to store the sequence as an integer, then translate it to string. Or else store a parallel integer column that is incremented at the same time as the alpha value. Either way, you could sort on the integer column.

Answer (score 0):

A problem here is that you can't really tell from the data where the "last" entry is unless there is more detail as to how the old entries are deleted.

If I understand correctly, you are wrapping around at the end of the sequence, which means you must be deleting some of your old data to make space. However if the data isn't deleted in a perfectly uniform manner, you'll end up with fragments, like below:

```
ABCD   HIJKL NOPQRS   WXYZ
```

You'll notice that there is no obvious next value...D could be the last value created, but it might also be L or S.

At best you could look for the first or last missing element (use a stored procedure to perform a x+1 check just like you would to find a missing element in an integer sequence), but it's not going to provide any special result for rolled-over lists.

Comment: The sequence doesn't always start at the beginning.  Sometimes, it starts at BBBB, while sometimes it starts at YYYY, so there's already "room" at the beginning of the alphabet

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't feel like writing code to increment letters, I'd create a table of all valid IDs (AAAAAA through ZZZZZZ) with an integer from 1 to X for those IDs. Then you can use the following:

```
SELECT @max_id = MAX(id) FROM Possible_Silly_IDs

SELECT
    COALESCE(MAX(PSI2.silly_id), 'AAAAAA')
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN Possible_Silly_IDs PSI1 ON
    PSI1.silly_id = T1.silly_id
INNER JOIN Possible_Silly_IDs PSI2 ON
    PSI2.id = CASE WHEN PSI1.id = @max_id THEN 1 ELSE PSI1.id + 1 END
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.silly_id = PSI2.silly_id
WHERE
    T2.silly_id IS NULL
```

The COALESCE is there in case the table is empty. To be truly robust you should calculate the 'AAAAAA' (SELECT @min_silly_id = silly_id WHERE id = 1) in case your "numbering" algorithm changes.

If you really wanted to do things right, you'd redo the database design as has been suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To return the next `ID` for a given `ID` (with rollover), use:

```
SELECT  COALESCE
        (
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   id > @id
        ORDER BY
                id
        ),
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    mytable
        ORDER BY
                id
        )
        ) AS nextid
```

This query searches for the `ID` next to the given. If there is no such `ID`, it returns the first `ID`.

Here are the results:

```
WITH mytable AS
        (
        SELECT  'AAA' AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'BBB' AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'CCC' AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'DDD' AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  'EEE' AS id
        )
SELECT  mo.id,
        COALESCE
        (
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.id > mo.id
        ORDER BY
                id
        ),
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    mytable mi
        ORDER BY
                id
        )
        ) AS nextid
FROM    mytable mo

id      nextid
-----   ------
AAA     BBB
BBB     CCC
CCC     DDD
DDD     EEE
EEE     AAA
```

, i. e. it returns `BBB` for `AAA`, `CCC` for `BBB`, etc., and, finally, `AAA` for `EEE` which is last in the table.